# String Search in files and populate results as Drop Down list or Combo Box in VB6(Visual basic)

Tags: vb6

I want to store string variable from the user and then I want to search that string in files of a specific folder. I want to match the stored string within each file. If I find a match to the string, I want a list box or Combo box to be populated with the name of the files. I am working in Visual basic (VB6).

I tried Some VB.net code like getfiles() but those are not working in VB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you index the target folder you can use Windows Search:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const INDEXED_FOLDER_PATH As String = _
    "C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.16299.0\um"

Private WithEvents CN As ADODB.Connection

Private Sub CN_ExecuteComplete( _
    ByVal RecordsAffected As Long, _
    ByVal pError As ADODB.Error, _
    ByRef adStatus As ADODB.EventStatusEnum, _
    ByVal pCommand As ADODB.Command, _
    ByVal pRecordset As ADODB.Recordset, _
    ByVal pConnection As ADODB.Connection)

    If adStatus <> adStatusOK Then
        MousePointer = vbDefault
        'Sadly this DSO is lazy about providing a Description here, so it
        'will often be empty along with an empty Errors collection.
        MsgBox "Error " & pError.Number & vbNewLine _
             & vbNewLine _
             & pError.Description
    Else
        With pRecordset
            If .EOF Then
                List1.AddItem "*no hits*"
            Else
                Do Until .EOF
                    List1.AddItem .Fields(0).Value
                    .MoveNext
                Loop
            End If
            .Close
        End With
        MousePointer = vbDefault
    End If
    Text1.SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    MousePointer = vbHourglass
    List1.Clear
    'We are doing an async request here because depending on what we are asking
    'for it might take a few seconds:
    CN.Execute "SELECT System.ItemNameDisplay" _
             & " FROM SystemIndex" _
             & " WHERE DIRECTORY='file:" & Replace$(INDEXED_FOLDER_PATH, "\", "/") & "'" _
             & " AND FREETEXT('" & Text1.Text & "')", _
             , _
             adCmdText Or adAsyncExecute
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
    CN.Open "Provider=Search.CollatorDSO;Extended Properties='Application=Windows'"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
    CN.Close
End Sub
```

[image: screenshot]

More info: [Querying the Index with Windows Search SQL Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231256(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Many Thanks @bob77 but which Argument I have to pass to CN_ExecuteComplete function and from where those argument taking value and also could you please mention the flow of the above code.

Comment: The `CN_ExecuteComplete` event handler is called by the Connection object `CN` when execution of the query completes.  Your code doesn't pass parameters to it, the Connection object does.  The query is made in the `Command1_Click` event handler.  The key to this is use of the `adAsyncExecute` option.

Comment: Be sure that the folder you target has been indexed.  Use the Control Panel applet "Indexing Options" to accomplish this.